# How to weight data according to multiple variables

Tags: r, stratification, weighted-data

I have two datasets.  Dataset A is considered the population.  It has 7 variables with different number of classes / breaks for each.  Dataset B is the dataset I want to make look like Dataset A in terms of variable distributions. For example, Dataset A has 40% men and 60% women.  Dataset B has 45% men and 55% women.  I want to give a weight to every record in Dataset B so that the overall distribution becomes like A, i.e., 40% men and 60 % women.  I wrote the code below to stratify on 1 variable (`Child_Present`), but ultimately I want to stratify on 7 variables.  Does anyone know how to do this for multiple strata?

```
B <- read.table("C:/DatasetB.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
preliminary.design <- svydesign(id=~1, data=B)
ps.weights <- data.frame(Child_Present=c(1,2), Freq=c(5,5))
mydesign <- postStratify(preliminary.design, strata=~Child_Present, 
                         population=ps.weights)
df <- data.frame(unlist(attr(mydesign$postStrata[[1]], "weights")))
write.table(df, "c:/testy.txt", sep="\t")
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting & viable question for the site. But note that if you are only asking for R code, it would be off topic here. I edited the title to make it less software specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind using other software than R, you can do this using the www.spinnakerresearch.nl weight module. Upload dataset B and for each strata enter the distribution percentage found in dataset A. The module uses IPF (iterative proportional fitting) to calculate line item weight factors ultimately matching dataset A.